# With an array of strings of equal length, get the nth character of each string in it's own array using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

So this is my first question on StackOverflow so I apologize if I'm breaking any conventions here...

I've got an array of variable length, where each element is a string (each string element is of the same length). I need to get the nth character of each string in that array into it's own array.

In very simple terms I have the following:

```
string[] source = new string[3] { "abcd", "efgh", "ijkl" };
```

and want to return:

```
string[] output = new string[4] { "aei", "bfj", "cgk", "dhl" };
```

Again this is very simplified because in reality I'm dealing with MB of data, which is why I need a solution using LINQ and not just a bunch of nested for loops.

Thanks in advance everybody!

Comment: I don't know what kind of code this is, you this clearly isn't C#... source would be like string[] source = new string[] {"abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"}...
More than this. Welcome to S.O. I welcome you to go read the following and then edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? How is the behavior of your code different from the expected behavior? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: string[] output = source.Select(x => x.Select((y, i) => new { chr = y, index = i })).SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => x.index).Select(x => string.Join("", x.Select(y => y.chr))).ToArray();

Comment: Perhaps you didn't know that nested `for` loops are likely to be faster than LINQ, and quite possibly a lot faster depending on how you use LINQ.

Comment: I think you might not understand what LINQ is. LINQ to Objects is simply a bunch of loops hidden behind methods. They are not magic; there's no way to actually loop over a sequence without writing a loop *somewhere*. The purpose of LINQ is not to be faster than loops; the purpose of LINQ is to *make your code read like its semantics rather than reading like a bunch of additions to indexes*.

Comment: @KevinAvignon yea...that wasn't what I'd originally posted, someone decided they knew better what I meant that I did and modified the original post (which I did make a couple mistakes in admittedly); I've corrected it now so it is actual C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test shows that setting @jdweng's purely LINQ solution 1X, a solution somewhat abusing LINQ to do indexing comes in at 7.4X and a solution using `for` comes in at 28.4X.

(Ab)using LINQ with indexing:

```
var c = Enumerable.Range(0, source[0].Length).Select(chpos => Enumerable.Range(0, source.Length).Select(si => source[si][chpos]).Join()).ToArray();
```

Using nested `for` loops:

```
var sourcelen = source.Length;
var strlen = source[0].Length;
var c = new String[strlen];
var sb = new StringBuilder(strlen);
for (int chpos = 0; chpos < strlen; ++chpos) {
    for (int si = 0; si < sourcelen; ++si)
        sb.Append(source[si][chpos]);
    c[chpos] = sb.ToString();
    sb.Length = 0;
}
```

Running some further tests, `Append` is a little faster then indexing the `StringBuilder` until there are a lot of long strings and building all the strings in parallel (sequentially) isn't faster, and as the strings increase in length, a `Parallel.For` version catches up to the fastest nested `for` version and then surpasses it, if you have a large number (10,000) of strings. Interestingly `Append` is much slower than indexing in `Parallel`.

Here is the build each indexed parallel version:

```
    var sourcelen = source.Length;
    var strlen = source[0].Length;
    var c = new String[strlen];
    Parallel.For(0, strlen, chpos => {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(sourcelen);
        sb.Length = sourcelen;
        for (int si = 0; si < sourcelen; ++si)
            sb[si] = source[si][chpos];
        c[chpos] = sb.ToString();
    });
```

Using this `Join` extension method greatly speeds up the solutions that use `String.Join(String.Empty,` or `String.Join("",`:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<char> src) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in src)
        sb.Append(c);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Some notes on timings: Using LINQPad, I wrote some code to generate a sample `source`:

```
var lens = 10000;
var source = new string[10000];
//
{
    var s = Enumerable.Range(0,26).Select(letternum => new String(Convert.ToChar('a'+letternum), lens)).ToArray();
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < source.Length; ++j1)
        source[j1] = s[j1 % 26].ToString();
}
```

Then, using LINQPad's `Util.ElapsedTime`, I measured the time to process `source` with various implementations:

```
TimeSpan basetime;
//
{
    var start = Util.ElapsedTime;
    var c = source.Select(x => x.Select((y, i) => new { chr = y, index = i })).SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => x.index).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.chr).Join()).ToArray();
    basetime = Util.ElapsedTime - start;
    basetime.Dump("Elapsed LINQ My Join 1X");
    //c.Dump();
}
//
{
    var start = Util.ElapsedTime;
    var sourcelen = source.Length;
    var strlen = source[0].Length;
    var c = new String[strlen];
    Parallel.For(0, strlen, chpos => {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(sourcelen);
        sb.Length = sourcelen;
        for (int si = 0; si < sourcelen; ++si)
            sb[si] = source[si][chpos];
        c[chpos] = sb.ToString();
    });
    var myt = Util.ElapsedTime - start;
    myt.Dump($"Elapsed build each indexed parallel {basetime.TotalSeconds / myt.TotalSeconds:0.0}X");
    c.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Sorry this project got shelved for a long time as some personal life stuff came up. You are clearly a much more experienced developer than I as I have a bit if difficulty following your solution.

I have no idea how you tested the efficiency of the various methods you talked about. I originally took the method you described as 1X speed, and now seeing your abuse method I understand how that works.

But I'm failing to grasp how that Parallel.For loop works and when I try to run a test of it against the string I used as an example originally it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: @MikeAbraham Sorry, the Parallel version had an error. I have expanded my answer with fixes for that version and notes on how I did timings.